# JQuery .validate() TypeError: a.validator.methods[method]

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, jquery-validate

I'm trying to validate a registration form (below) but can't actually get the form to POST, simply because my vlaidation is failing somewhere I guess. Firebug reports this error every time the form is submitted:

`TypeError: a.validator.methods[j] is undefined`

I thought it was because I might have duplicate field or div ID's somewhere, so I prepended all ID's and names with 'reg' (I.E. regemail, regusername); with no luck.

Any ideas?

## HTML Registration Form

```
    <form class="register-form" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
    <h3 style="text-align: center;">Create your account</h3>

    <label>First Name</label>
    <div class="input-icon">
        <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="regfn" id="regfn" />
    </div>

    <label>Last Name</label>
    <div class="input-icon">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="regln" id="regln" />
    </div>

    <label>Email Address</label>
    <div class="input-icon">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" name="regemail" id="regemail" />
    </div>

    <label>Verify Email</label>
    <div class="input-icon">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Re-type Your Email Address" name="regvemail" id="regvemail"/>
    </div>

    <label>Username</label>
    <div class="input-icon">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="regusername" id="regusername"/>
    </div>

    <label>Password</label>
    <div class="input-icon">
            <input type="password" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password" name="regpassword" id="regpassword" />
    </div>

    <label>Re-type Your Password</label>
    <div class="input-icon">
        <input type="password" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Re-type Your Password" name="regvpassword" id="regvpassword" />

    <label>
        <div class="input-icon">
        <input type="checkbox" name="regterms" id="regterms" /> Check this box if you agree to our
        <a href="#" style="color:#FFF;"><u>Terms of Service</u></a> and <a href="#" style="color:#FFF;"><u>Privacy Policy</u></a>. You cannot register otherwise.</div><br /><br />
        </div>
    </label>

    <div id="regajaxerrorregister"></div>

    <button id="register-back-btn" type="button" class="btn">
    <i class="m-icon-swapleft"></i> Back </button>

    <button type="submit" id="register-submit-btn" name="register-submit-btn" class="btn green pull-right">
    Register <i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i>
    </button>

</form>
```

## JQuery Validation

```
    $('.register-form').validate({
        errorElement: 'label', //default input error message container
        errorClass: 'help-inline', // default input error message class
        focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
        ignore: "",
        rules: {
            regfn: {
               required: true,
               maxlength: 16,
               alphanumerical: true
            },
            regln: {
               required: true,
               maxlength: 16
            },
            regemail: {
               required: true,
               email: true
            },
            regvemail: {
               required: true,
               email: true,
               equalTo: "#regemail"
            },
            regusername: {
               required: true,
               minlength: 4,
               maxlength: 12                  
            },
            regpassword: {
               required: true,
               minlength: 6,
               maxlength: 20
            },
            regvpassword: {
               required: true,
               minlength: 6,
               equalTo: '#regpassword'
            },
            regregterms: {
               required: true
            },
        },

        messages: {
            regfn: {
               required: "All fields are required.",
               maxlength: "Maximum of 16 characters"
            },
            regln: {
               required: "All fields are required.",
               maxlength: "Maximum of 16 characters"
            },
            regemail: {
               required: "All fields are required."
            },
            regvemail: {
               required: "All fields are required.",
               equalTo: "Your emails do not match - please check them."
            },
            regusername: {
               required: "All fields are required.",
               minlength: "Minimum of 4 characters",
               maxlength: "Maximum of 12 characters"                       
            },
            regpassword: {
               required: "All fields are required.",
               minlength: "Minimum of 6 characters",
               maxlength: "Maximum of 20 characters",
            },
            regvpassword: {
               required: "All fields are required.",
               equalTo: "The passwords do not match."
            },
            regterms: {
               required: "Please agree to the terms and conditions and privacy policy."
            },
        },

        invalidHandler: function (event, validator) { //display error alert on form submit   

        },

        highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
            $(element)
                .closest('.control-group').addClass('error'); // set error class to the control group
        },

        success: function (label) {
            label.closest('.control-group').removeClass('error');
            label.remove();
        },              

        submitHandler: function (form) {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'pages/login/registration.php',
                data: "fn="+document.getElementById("regfn").value+"&ln="+document.getElementById("regln").value+"&username="+document.getElementById("regusername").value+"&email="+document.getElementById("regemail").value+"&password="+document.getElementById("regpassword").value,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(htmldata) {
                    if (htmldata.result=="success"){  
                        location.href ="profile.php"; 
                    }else{ 
                        $('#regajaxerrorregister').html(htmldata.msg);
                    }
                }
            });         
        },

        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.addClass('help-small no-left-padding').insertAfter(element.closest('.input-icon'));
        }

    }); //register form
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for the long post!

Comment: You can't do that otherwise the AJAX post and JQuery validation will be ignored. It's the same with all my 50+ forms, but this is the only one that doesn't work. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: The form doesn't have `id="register-form"`, so `$("#register-form")` doesn't select anything.

Comment: I apologise @Barmar, It's actually `$('.register-form').validate({` - I copied and pasted the issue code here half way through making changes, but good eye. I'll reflect it above.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the issue is being identified with this `TypeError: a.validator.methods[j] is undefined` from `jquery.validate.min.js`, let me format the file and see what the line number is, I'll copy the block here (I haven't edited this file)

Comment: While debugging, use the non-minified library.

Comment: I'm sorry folks but there is nothing to see here, the issue was caused by an additional comma accidentally inserted in another .js file. Kick in the teeth for nothing! Thanks for your help all! I've flagged it for closure due to a typographical error.

Answer (score 3):

There's no jQuery validation method `alphanumerical`, it's `alphanumeric`:

```
        regfn: {
           required: true,
           maxlength: 16,
           alphanumeric: true
        },
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/RT6Ue/6/)

Also, make sure you're loading `additonal-methods.min.js` to get this method.

I'm not sure you should use this for the first name, since names can also contain hyphen (`-`).

Comment: Hi there, alphanumerical is a method that I have created and it does exist. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I take it the additional comma was in the file that defined the alphanumerical method, so it didn't get defined.

Comment: No, the additional comma was in another file called app.js in a function that was only called on the registration page to do with the fading background images. I didn't notice that it wasn't working because I hadn't yet uploaded the images for the fader. Amateur mistake on my part.